# cannot convert from 'ref object' to 'tagVARIANT*'

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper, command-line-interface, variant

I have a method in C++/CLI that uses VARIANT* as a parameter. Whenever I invoke the method in C#, passing a null object as the VARIANT* parameter, I get compile errors.

ERROR:

```
Argument #: cannot convert from 'ref object' to 'tagVARIANT*'
```

Here's the C++/CLI method:

```
int foo::fooMethod( VARIANT* varFoo)
{
...
return 1
}
```

C# code(which references the C++ DLL):

```
foo test = new foo();
object objFoo;
int iRet = foo.fooMethod( ref objFoo );
```

Comment: Is this a direct copy/paste from your source code?  It mentions "ref object" in the error message, but your sample code makes no use of the 'ref' keyword.

Comment: this is not a copy/paste of the actual code, sorry i forgot to add ref.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conversion from System::Object^ to a COM Automation VARIANT is only ever automatic when you let the CLR call a COM interface method.  Seeing it appear in native code is fairly unusual, do make sure that you are not bypassing the normal COM interop option.  Readily usable from C# or VB.NET code, just add a reference to the type library.

Simply declare the argument as `Object^` instead.  If you *really* need a VARIANT then you can get one from [Marshal::GetNativeVariantForObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4x7tby7x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for your answer. Can you please elaborate more on this. What do you mean by "not bypassing the normal COM interop option". Sorry, but I'm just newbie on COM.

Comment: This really needs to start by you explaining why you wrote this code.  I cannot guess at it, what fooMethod() does is completely invisible.